# How do I use php to create a database with table and info using a backup file?

Tags: php, sql

How do I use  php to create a database with table and info using a backup file?

so far my code is

```
<?
header("content-type:text/plain");

$serv= mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'xxxx');

if($serv){
        wText("Server connection created");
}
else{
    wText("Server connection failed");

}

$sql ="CREATE DATABASE tf2faq";

if(@mysql_query($sql,$serv)){

    wText("Database tf2faq created");
}
else{wText("Database tf2faq create failed");}




$sql = 'CREATE TABLE `tf2faq`.`loadoutitems` (`item` TEXT NULL, `class` TEXT NULL, `type` TEXT NULL, `replaces` TEXT NULL, `itempos` TEXT NULL, `modpos` TEXT NULL, `modneg` TEXT NULL, `imgurl` TEXT NULL, `notes` TEXT NULL) ENGINE = MyISAM';
mysql_query($sql,$serv);
if(@mysql_query($sql,$serv)){
wText("table loadoutitems created");
}
else{
wText("table loadoutitems create failed");

}

$sql="LOAD DATA INFILE 'loadoutitmsfx.csv' INTO TABLE  `tf2faq`.'loadoutitems'";

if(@mysql_query($sql,$serv)){
wText("Data Load Passed");
}
else{
wText("Data Load Failed");
}



function wText($txt){
    echo $txt . "\n";
}
?>
```

it fails on the LOAD DATA line, not sure why.

*edit* in my code i removed the "@" in there and it still says the file load failed

Comment: I know why you're "not sure why". Because you 're using error suppress operator @. Remove it and look at the error message/code of mysql_query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is loadoutitmsfx.csv? The file needs to be on the computer where the database is running. You might try specifying the whole path to it. Something like "/home/jim/loadoutitmsfx.csv".

Do the number of columns from your csv file and the table match up?

You probably need to specify some more options to get csv working.

LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/jim/loadoutitmsfx.csv' INTO TABLE  tf2faq.loadoutitems
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

Additionally don't use @.

Comment: the script will be uploaded to the webserver which is also the database comp, so think of this as a mated pair,

the way i did it was to call the php realpath() and replace the \ with a \\ 
so your line LOAD DATA INFILE reapath(file location).replace("\","\\") INTO TABLE tf2faq.loadoutitems FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

i used the inheritance for example as i know not proper code, but whether there was a "@" or not it threw no error so i had to use 
echo mysql_error() to get the error that should have been thrown, your import is correct

Answer (score 0):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` is disabled on most MySQL servers, as it doesn't work with remote database servers and requires the data file to be readable by the database server. Parse the file yourself and generate SQL statements.